# Как перебрать элементы многомерного массива не по очереди, а попарно, (пример кода внутри)

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть многомерный массив к примеру такой:

```
<?php
    $prod = array(
      array(
        "Название" => "Первый продукт",
        "Производитель" => "Япония",
        "Год выпуска" => 2016
      ),
      array(
        "Название" => "Второй продукт",
        "Производитель" => "Корея",
        "Год выпуска" => 2016
      ),
      array(
        "Название" => "Третий продукт",
        "Производитель" => "Россия",
        "Год выпуска" => 2014
      )
    );
    echo '<table><tbody>';
    foreach($prod as $value){
        echo '<tr><td>';
        foreach($value as $key => $val){
            echo '<td>'.$key .'=>'. $val.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
    ?>
```

Я хочу сделать из него таблицу, в которой каждая строка будет отдельной характеристикой, а каждая ячейка в этой строке должна быть одним из вариантов этой характеристики.

ТО есть чтобы в первой строке у меня были 3 ячейки с названиями, во второй - с производителями, а в третьей год, и тд. количество характеристик у меня постоянно меняется, мозг сломал получалось разное, и только сегодня понял что характеристики должны построчно записываться, а максимум что получилось это записать отдельную характеристику в отдельную ячейку что совсем нехорошо.

Должно получиться так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть если у вас в массиве 1000 производителей, то в первой строке таблицы должно быть 1000 ячеек с их наименованиями?

Comment: Внятное объяснение, попытка решения, пример правильного вывода - я в раю вопросов? :) Даже плюсую от радости.

Comment: Да все верно, это таблица сравнения характеристик. Люди привыкли сравнивать характеристики по горизонтали, но как горизонтально вывести ума не рпиложу

Comment: @Other еще бы мне в рай ответов попасть))

Comment: Сейчас набросаю.

Comment: А вы это из БД достаете? Ибо если так, то, кмк, в запросе можно сгруппировать по характеристикам, в php уже пройтись циклом.... то есть выборка будет такая: `название => первый,второй,третий; производитель => япония,корея,россия; год выпуска => 2016,2015,2014`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут система управления и она только такой вариант вывода предлагает, конечно могу запросами к бд можно вывести так как хочу, но думал что есть какой то вариант попроще, на основе уже сформированных массивов.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов как раз таки вариант попроще —  сделать правильный запрос к БД. Ибо для формирования таблицы надо сделать пару циклов, чтоб сгруппировать данные, для начала, а потом еще пара циклов, чтобы вывести. Не думаю, что 4 полных цикла по всем данным с фильтрацией  проще, чем выборка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$prod = [
  [
    "Название" => "Первый продукт",
    "Производитель" => "Япония",
    "Год выпуска" => 2016
  ], [
    "Название" => "Второй продукт",
    "Производитель" => "Корея",
    "Год выпуска" => 2016
  ], [
    "Название" => "Третий продукт",
    "Производитель" => "Россия",
    "Год выпуска" => 2014
  ], [
    "Название" => "X продукт",
    "Год выпуска" => 2042
  ]
];

$data = [];
foreach($prod as $item){
  foreach(array_keys($item) as $key){
    // Если ключа нет, создаём его
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $data))
      $data[$key] = [];

    // Добавляем к ключу ещё один элемент
    $data[$key][] = $item[$key];
  }
}

$table = '<table>';
foreach($data as $th => $td){
  // Открываем новую строку с названием
  $row = '<tr><th>' . $th . '</th>';

  // Если у текущего набора нет каких-то элементов (просто не передали), дополняем пустой строкой (можно написать )
  // Можно оставить пустую строку, но для создания валидной таблицы заполнить надо (td создаются)
  if(count($td) - 1 < count($prod))
    $td = array_merge($td, array_fill(0, count($prod) - count($td), '<em>No data</em>'));

  // Далее пояснять, надеюсь, не нужно
  foreach($td as $cell){
    $row .= '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
  }
  $table .= $row . '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';

var_dump($table);
```

https://repl.it/GHh9/0